# Сравнение массивов в std::array

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, операторы, класс

Реализую класс, аналогичный `std::array`. Одним из пунктов является перегрузка операторов сравнения массивов одинаковой длины (лексикографическое). С операторами == и != все понятно, но как работают <=, >=, <, >? Вот мой вариант и он неверный. Подскажите, что я делаю не так и как исправить ситуацию?

```
    bool operator< (Array const& v1, Array const& v2) {
        bool res = false;
        int i = 0;
        while (v1[i] == v2[i]) {
            ++i;
        }
        if (v1[i] < v2[i]) {
            res = true;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Остальные операторы сделал по той же логике.

Comment: явно не хватает проверки, что i вышло за пределы массива

Comment: Вообще-то операции меньше и больше для массивов, это как-то не очень понятно, что, нет?

Comment: почему нет? там сказано - лексикографически. все нормально

Answer (score 2, accepted):

где то так

```
bool operator< (Array const& v1, Array const& v2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {
      if (v1[i] < v2[i]) return true; // нашли элемент, который больше, готово, выходим
      if (v1[i] > v2[i]) return false; // условие точно не выполняется, уходим
      // элементы одинаковые. крутим массив дальше
    }
    return false; // массивы оказались одинаковыми. что ж.
}
```

ну а если нет запрета на стандартную библиотеку, то можно посмотреть на [std::mismatch](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch)

Comment: А разная длина если?

Comment: перед циклом сначала сравниваются размеры..

Comment: У `std::array` размер — часть типа. У аналога, вероятно, тоже. Следовательно, т.к. тип параметров у `operator<` совпадает, то совпадают и размеры. Теоретически.

Answer (score 0):

Если экземпляры `Array` могут иметь разные размеры, то надо учесть возможность что один массив окажется короче другого. В примере ниже `Array::size` возвращает размер массива (почему-то `int`). Цикл надо прогнать до минимума размеров обоих массивов. Если разница до сих пор не найдена, то надо анализировать длины массивов. Массив меньшей длины в такой ситуации считается меньшим в лексиграфическом смысле:

```
bool operator <(Array const& a, Array const& b) {
    int const min_size = std::min(a.size(), b.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < min_size; ++i) {
        if (a[i] < b[i]) {
            return true;
        }
        if (b[i] < a[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return b.size() > min_size;
}
```